How to set a flexible height for a TabBarView with a minimum height?
I am working on a Flutter app where I need a TabBarView. The height of the TabBarView should be flexible.
It should have a minimum height of 500. If the content inside the TabBarView exceeds 500, it should expand to fit the content.
If it is not possible to specify a minimum, the height expands to fit the content.
Here is the relevant code snippet:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded),
          iconSize: 20,
          color: kWhiteColor,
          onPressed: () => Get.back(result: true),
        ),
        title: const Text(
          'الشباك',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: kWhiteColor),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent, // Disable default overlay
      ),
      body: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: [
            _buildHeaderSection(),
            SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(40)),
            _buildStatsRow(),
            SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(40)),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kWhiteColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Color(0x19000000),
                    blurRadius: 20,
                    offset: Offset(0, 10),
                    spreadRadius: 0,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  _buildTabs(),
                  SizedBox(   <----------------------
                    height: 500,   <----------------------
                    child: TabBarView(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      children: [
                        buildTicketCountTab(filteredEvents),
                        buildTicketRevenueTab(filteredEvents),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


We need to know what's inside these TabBarView's children widgets, buildTicketCountTab(filteredEvents) and
buildTicketRevenueTab(filteredEvents), You can make it a shortened version of it...

Did you mean by,

It should have a minimum height of 500. If the content inside the
TabBarView exceeds 500, it should expand to fit the content.

Where your...
SizedBox(   <----------------------
  height: 500,   <----------------------
  child: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: [
      buildTicketCountTab(filteredEvents),
      buildTicketRevenueTab(filteredEvents),
    ],
  ),
),

should be replaced with...
Expanded(
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 500),
    child: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: [
      buildTicketCountTab(filteredEvents),
      buildTicketRevenueTab(filteredEvents),
    ],
  ),
),

You can still use it if it suits your use case...
UPDATE:
However, if it still introduces an exception, such as.

error ════ Exception caught by rendering library
═════════════════════════════════ RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderClipRect#26cb2 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 2164
pos 12: 'hasSize'

Please ensure that the buildTicketCountTab(filteredEvents) and buildTicketRevenueTab(filteredEvents) TabBarView's children widgets are properly laid out first (i.e., it produces or renders output), including other widgets that expand based on data.
If it is properly laid out, here's what you can do:
Under this code block:
SizedBox(   <----------------------
  height: 500,   <----------------------
  child: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: [
      buildTicketCountTab(filteredEvents),
      buildTicketRevenueTab(filteredEvents),
    ],
  ),
),

Modify it into:
SizedBox(
  height: 500,
  child: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: buildTicketCountTab(filteredEvents),
        ),
      ), // Please verify it if it is necessary
      SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: buildTicketRevenueTab(filteredEvents),
        ),
      ), // Please verify it if it is necessary
    ],
  ),
),

Please test it thoroughly to avoid confusion.
I hope it helps!

Thank you for trying to help
But this method caused this error
════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderClipRect#26cb2 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2164 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Do these two widgets buildTicketCountTab(filteredEvents) and
buildTicketRevenueTab(filteredEvents) generates unbounded height? Can you update your question to see its layout?
